# No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to upload file like pdf or jpg to my firebase and update my collection 'solde' witch store all data from the id of the element. My front look like this :

```
//
//  UserSolde.swift
//  ML2V_IOS
//
//  Created by Clément Enjolras on 05/09/2023.
//

import SwiftUI
import FirebaseStorage
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

struct UserSolde: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @StateObject var soldemodel = SoldeModel()
    @State private var soldes: [Solde] = []
    @State private var isDocumentPickerPresented = false
    @State private var selectedURL: URL?
    @State private var selectedSoldeID: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        content.onAppear{
            Task{
                do{
                    try await soldemodel.getAllSolde()
                    soldes = soldemodel.resultsolde
                }catch{
                    print("Erreur lors de la récupération des soldes : \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var content: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Mes Soldes").font(.system(size: 24).bold())
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "creditcard")
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                    .background(Color(.white))
            }.padding(.horizontal)
            
            List($soldes){ solde in
                
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("Total du solde en cours").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
//error here
                        Text("\(solde.total)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Etat de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
//same error here
                        Text("\(solde.etat)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Date d'émission").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
//also here
                        Text("\(solde.date)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        selectedSoldeID = solde.id
                        isDocumentPickerPresented.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                Text("Envoyer la facture").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }.sheet(isPresented: $isDocumentPickerPresented) {
                                
                                DocumentPickerView(selectedURL: $selectedURL,soldeDataId:$selectedSoldeID)
                            }
                }
            }
            
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                HStack{
                    Text("DEMANDER MON SOLDE").fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                    
                }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32, height: 48)
            }.background(Color(.systemBlue)).cornerRadius(10).padding(.top,24)
            
        
            NavigationLink {
                UserDashboard().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            } label: {
                HStack(spacing: 3){
                    Text("Retour à la page")
                    Text("Principale").fontWeight(.bold)
                }.font(.system(size: 14))
            }
        }
    }
}

private func formatDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

//Mettre à jour firestore et firebase avec la facture
func uploadInvoice(url:String,iddocument:String,filename:String){

}

struct DocumentPickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var selectedURL: URL?
    @Binding var soldeDataId: String?

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.png,.pdf,.jpeg,], asCopy: true)
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        // No update needed
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        let parent: DocumentPickerView

        init(_ parent: DocumentPickerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            if let selectedURL = urls.first {
                parent.selectedURL = selectedURL
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UserSolde_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UserSolde()
    }
}
```

The goal is to link my file with my firebase. To acheive that I would like to store my solde id as I already did but as soon as I store $selectedsoldeid in my docupicker I got this error : No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'.
I'm new on swift can you explain me why ? As soon as I got the id of my 'solde' it will be okay for me

Already try to change many time my code but the problem is to pass the id to modify my collection and link data

Comment: What type are `solde.total`, `solde.date` etc? Can you show the declaration of `Solde`?

Comment: import Foundation

struct Solde: Identifiable,Codable{
    var id: String
    var date: Date
    var etat: String
    var facture: String
    var proprietaire: String
    var total:Int
}

Comment: This is how the solde is written

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/init(_:rowcontent:)-4c78v) of `List`. Notice that it takes a closure of type `(Binding<Solde>) -> RowContent`.

This means that the `solde` closure parameter is a `Binding<Solde>`. `solde.total`, `solde.date` etc are all of type `Binding<Int>`, `Binding<Date>` etc. The custom string interpolation for `Text` doesn't support these types. And in any case, your intention is to interpolate the `Int` and `Date` values, not the bindings.

Just access the `wrappedValue` of these bindings to get the `Int`, `Date` etc.

Example:

```
Text("\(solde.total.wrappedValue)")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's is my final code for people who have the issue :

```html
List($soldes){ solde in
                
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("Total du solde en cours").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.total.wrappedValue)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Etat de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.etat.wrappedValue)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Date d'émission").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.date.wrappedValue)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        selectedSoldeID = solde.id
                        isDocumentPickerPresented.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                Text("Envoyer la facture").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }.sheet(isPresented: $isDocumentPickerPresented) {
                                
                                DocumentPickerView(selectedURL: $selectedURL,soldeDataId:$selectedSoldeID)
                            }
                }
            }
```